# SQL select to display latest record

Tags: sql, oracle, select, top-n

So here is a case where one of the column in a table has same values for multiple records but the `Date` column has incremental values.

```
ID| PAY_CODE| RATE  |   Date
---------------------------------
1 |  1111   |  50   | 2017-01-01
2 |  1111   |  50   | 2017-02-01
3 |  1111   |  50   | 2017-03-11
4 |  1111   |  50   | 2017-05-21
```

How can I print only the latest record if the latest `Date` entered is unknown?

Expected result:

```
ID| PAY_CODE| RATE  |   Date
---------------------------------
4 |  1111   |  50   | 2017-05-21
```

I need a SQL query which internally compares the `Date` column and returns the highest value (Latest date in this case) - is  this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2);
```

Comment: This will return multiple rows if they are tied for the latest date.

Comment: @MT0 . . . "but the Date column has incremental values."

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `rank` window function:

```
SELECT id, pay_code, rate, date
FROM   (SELECT id, pay_code, rate, date, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY data DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: This will return multiple rows if they are tied for the latest date; using `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK` will only return a single row.

Comment: @MT0 OP requested the rows from the latest date. As far as I understand it, allowing multiple results is the intended behavior. If the requirement is indeed to just return one of these rows, `row_number` will indeed do the trick,

Comment: The OP requested "How can I print only the latest record" but, regardless of what they intend, either `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from ( select * from table order by date desc) t
where rownum < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T WHERE T.DATE = ( SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM YOUR_TABLE)` this way you ensure you grab the latest result, other solutions using `TOP` could not work as expected